# Redirect to a filename that will be a variable and contain a command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting, variable

I'm using nmap to scan a network and then create an XML file that contains the scanned information. I want that XML file to contain the date of the scan so that each file is unique and I can see the time and date I did the scan, I'll be doing lots of scans of the same network, regularly. I use the date command to generate that.

```
nmap -sSV -oX scan_dmz_$(date +'%H'h'%M'm'%S's_'%d'-'%m'-'%Y').xml 10.0.0.0/24 10.1.0.0/24
```

However I want that XML filename to be put into a variable to be used by another command later (xsltproc) in the script that converts the XML into useful HTML files. Essentially the xsltproc command has to be aware of the name of the XML file created by nmap so that it can do its conversion.

```
xsltproc scan_dmz_12h00m00s_01-01-2023.XML -o DMZ_HTML_report.html
```

And I'm struggling with getting this XML filename into a variable so that xsltproc can use it. I've tried some really rudimentary bash scripting to just see how it works and I can't get it to function.

```
tail /var/log/auth.log > tailout=tail_$(date +'%H'h'%M'm'%S's_'%d'-'%m'-'%Y').xml ; xsltproc $tailout -o DMZ_HTML_report.html
```

Essentially how do I redirect to a variable filename which needs to become a variable at the same time so that a future command can work on that file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that there's no need to quote the `%` signs in the date format string, they're just ordinary characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First populate the variable, then use it.

```
tailout=tail_$(date +%Hh%Mm%Ss_%d-%m-%Y).xml
tail /var/log/auth.log > "$tailout"
xsltproc "$tailout" -o DMZ_HTML_report.html
```

Consider switching to `%FT%T%z` (equivalent to `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`) instead for the timestamp format. It's standard, unambiguous, universally understood, and when sorted lexically, sorts chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be to generate the variable and use it in subsequent invocations:

```
file="scan_dmz_$(date +'%Hh%Mm%Ss_%d-%m-%Y').xml"
nmap -sSV -oX "$file" 10.0.0.0/24 10.1.0.0/24
xsltproc "$file" -o DMZ_HTML_report.html
```

Or are you decoupling the scanning from `nmap` and the subsequent XSLT processing?

Incidentally, I'd personally use a YMD-HMS format structure for the file names (large to small): `"scan_dmz_$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').xml"`; it sorts more easily and close timed scans list lexically adjacent or nearby.